# How to Programmatically Create Firebird Database on Remote Server?

Tags: c#, firebird, remote-server

I am trying to create an application that can create a Firebird database remotely
- I have added FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient as a reference
- Copying fbclient.dll, fbembed.dll, icudt30.dll, icuin30.dll, icuuc30.dll in the debug folder.
and use the following code:

```
private void CreateDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.UserID = "SYSDBA";
    csb.Password = "masterkey";
    csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
    csb.Port = 3050;
    csb.DataSource = "Server-PC";
    csb.Database = @"D:\TestFirebird.GDB";
    FbConnection.CreateDatabase(csb.ConnectionString);
}
```

but it still raises an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to complete network request to host
>   "Server-PC".

What should I do?

Comment: are you sure that SYSDBA with that password can connect over port 3050 to that machine server-pc?does it work if you omit the database criteria?

Comment: you have to make sure that 1) server named "Server-PC" exists in your TCP network, is running, and is reachable by your developer computer 2) that server has Firebird Server installed AND running on it 3) Firebird Server running on "Server-PC" listens to the port 3050 4) firewalls and antiviruses on neither "Server-PC" nor your development machine do not block TCP connection between your application and Firebird Server application.  //// Also: ".GDB" extension is not recommended to use on Windows XP and further

Comment: @BugFinder it is not login/password issue, it is inability to make TCP connection from devel box to Server-PC:3050

Comment: I think you copy-pasted this connection string from an example, "Server-PC" is an unlikely hostname for any server. Note that copying fbclient.dll, fbembed.dll etc serves no purpose if you are using server type Default, as that will use a pure C# implementation to connect to the server: it doesn't use fbclient, and it doesn't use embedded in that case.